# Count the number of subsequence of length k from an array of size n

Tags: arrays, combinatorics, array-algorithms

Is there any direct formula to count the number of subsequences possible from an array of size n
It is not needed to be contiguous and  also not needed to be only distinct subsequences

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is formula for number of [combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination)

```
nCr(n, k) or C(n,k)  = n! / ((n-k)! * k!)
```